# How to plot grid seach layout and random search layout

Tags: python, search, plot, layout, grid

In Python I would like to create a plot like the one in the attached figure. Unfortunately I haven't found any code examples for this yet. Can someone help me, please?

[image]

Comment: Can you make your example more reproducible? Show some of the code, the data you have.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need this only as ilustration, so the data doesen't matter. The data can be as simple as possible...

Comment: Well it's a complex plot so will require a considerable plotting code. You can use matplotlib's `plt.subplot()` method to assign the number of subplots that you would like to have, then chart your plots on those 'grids'. The scatter will occupy most of the grids with two histograms plotted side by side on the top-most and left-most grids. Additionally I would recommend posting this at datascience.stackexchange since that is a more appropriate place to check for examples.

Comment: Also would recommend checking out the `yellow-brick` library. It's specifically made for plotting ML models and addresses the hassle of writing several lines of code to diagnose the modelling phase. Link: https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/